# getting sql records

Tags: php, mysql, sql

when i run this code, it returns the topic fine...

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT topic
FROM question 
WHERE id = '$id'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error());
        $topic = $row['topic'];
    }
```

but when I change it to this, it doesn't run at all.  why is this happening?

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT topic, lock
FROM question 
WHERE id = '$id'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error());
        $topic = $row['topic'];
        $lockedThread = $row['lock'];
        echo "here: " . $lockedThread;
    }
```

Comment: How exactly does it not run? Is there an error message you're getting?

Comment: Also, you're interpolating `$id` into your query, rather than passing it as a safe param.

Comment: i have this: error_reporting(1);

Comment: are you sure you have `lock` column ? mysql error occurs ?

Comment: @droidus: `$id` is a variable.  You don't show how it's populated, but if its from a user/webpage, you are putting it in open SQL code, thus allowing evil-doers to use SQL-Injection attacks.  Unless you are the one populating its considered unsafe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure `lock` is not a MySQL keyword (reserved word), you may have to backtick it (`` `lock` ``) in the field list:

```
SELECT `topic`, `lock`
...
```

[MySQL 5.6 Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html#table-reserved-words-5.6.5)

Comment: i don't believe it is a keyword.  how do I make sure?

Comment: whoa! the back-tick worked! why?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html#table-reserved-words-5.6.5 it is reserved